# JavaFx-selected theme not styling again

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have made theme selector in menu bar in javaFx program.
I made two menu items using radiomenuitem when select on any of the items then event handler fire and apply css according to their id if id = 1 then theme1.css will be apply like that.

(Note : this is controller class and I set scene and stage from main.java using setScene() and setStage() by default theme1.css is applied  )

now when I select item2 then theme2.css apply
but when I again select item1 its not reverting or not apply theme1.css

when I print on console then path appears correct.

so why its not applying css again to same scene?

do I have to refresh scene? or something I am missing .

I noticed one thing that ---
if I have three items

Item 1 /

Item 2

Item 3

and Item 1 is selected then theme1.css will be apply and when I select Item 2 then theme2.css will be apply and when I select Item 3 then theme3.css will be apply but now when I again select either Item 1 or Item 2

Then nothing changes :(

```
 private RadioMenuItem[] themes = new RadioMenuItem[]{new RadioMenuItem("Theme 1"),new RadioMenuItem("Theme 2")};
    private  String menuid;
    private Stage stage;
    private  Scene scene;
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

        ToggleGroup myToggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();

        themes[0].setToggleGroup(myToggleGroup);
        themes[1].setToggleGroup(myToggleGroup);

        themes[0].setId("1");
        themes[1].setId("2");
        themes[0].setSelected(true);
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> event = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                menuid = ((RadioMenuItem) e.getSource()).getId();
                if (((RadioMenuItem)e.getSource()).isSelected()) {
                    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/themes/theme"+menuid+".css").toExternalForm());
                    System.out.println("/themes/theme"+menuid+".css");
                    System.out.println(scene);
                    System.out.println(stage);
                    stage.setScene(scene);
                    System.out.println("scene sceee");
                }
            }
        };


        themes[0].setOnAction(event);
        themes[1].setOnAction(event);
        menutheme.getItems().addAll(themes);
}
  public void setStage(Stage primarystage){
        stage = primarystage;
    }
    public void setScene(Scene primaryscene){
        scene = primaryscene;
    }
```

[project files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NyZt.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok now I have solved that issue

First I should clear old stylesheet using clear()

like this

```
scene.getStylesheets().clear();
```